# IS this what we could expect best for 200 samples?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, optimization

I wonder if I'm going to land into the right part of the forum for this thread, appologies if I didn't.

This scene is meant for an eventual animations. I tweaked some parameters to reduce the noise as much as I could and render this view with 200 samples. It took 3:12min. This is the best so far I came up with 5 months of experience with modeling and blender.

I know it's not a regular question for this type of forum but I hope I can count onto your experience to get your point of view. (no pun)

-The main Light is coming though the windows. These are configured in order to avoid caustics.

-I used portals in front of these areas

-Currently using 2 Max bounces

-The exterior light comes from a HDRI with a ''sun'' area cranked up and a Sun lamp that definitely need some tweaks yet.

Question 1:At this point, I'm only wondering if I just have to crank up the samples or if I'm missing something important before boosting render times?

Question 2: Should I consider getting a better HDRI texture or tweaking something about the exterior light to help reducing noises?

Thanks for your input!

Charles

[image: Render Example 1]

[image: Showing the Main light sources]

[image: Just to Show the whole scene]

Comment: You simply need more samples. 200 is rarely enough. Try 500 with [denoising](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/settings/scene/render_layers/denoising.html#denoising) (if you are using version 2.79), or 1000 or more samples.

Comment: completely normal for 200 samples.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, even though this post as been marked as duplicate, I guess it is still interesting.

I played by the rules to optimize anything I could and I guess I cannot be the only one wondering if now is the actual time to crank up the samples.
(last hope for trying heavy render times)
Thanks for the suggestions! I'll give another try with more samples with an attempt to tweak the ''unforgiving'' denoiser.

Hope this posts helps someone else clarify their doubts before scheduling their Renders.